# mod_rewrite and redirect causing loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have problem when I try to redirect and rewrite together.
I have site **example.com/show_table.php?table=12** (max 99 tables). I wanted nice links, so I got this .htacces rw rule:

`RewriteRule ^table/([0-9]{1,2})$ show_table.php?table=$1 [L,NC]`

Now are links something like **example.com/table/12** - it's definitely OK. But I want all old links redirect to new format. So I use Redirect 301, I added to .htaccess this code:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} show_table.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^table=([0-9]{1,2})$
RewriteRule ^show_table\.php$ http://example.com/table/%1? [L,R=301,NC]`

But when I visit **example.com/show_table.php?table=12**, I receive just redir-loop. I don't understant - the first is rewrite, the second is redirection, there ain't no two redirections. Do You see any error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking `REQUEST_URI` in the condition, you need to be checking in `THE_REQUEST` (which contains the full *original* HTTP request, like `GET /show_table.php HTTP/1.1`).  When Apache performs the rewrite, it changes `REQUEST_URI`, so to the rewritten value, and that sends you into a loop.

```
# Match show_table.php in the input request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /show_table\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^table=([0-9]{1,2})$
# Do a full redirection to the new URL
RewriteRule ^show_table\.php$ http://example.com/table/%1? [L,R=301,NC]

# Then apply the internal rewrite as you already have working
RewriteRule ^table/([0-9]{1,2})$ show_table.php?table=$1 [L,NC]
```

You could get more specific in the `%{THE_REQUEST}` condition, but it should be sufficient and not harmful to use `show_table\.php` as the expression.

You'll want to read over the notes on `THE_REQUEST` over [at Apache's `RewriteCond` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Note: Technically, you can capture the query string in the same `RewriteCond` and reduce it to just one condition. This is a little shorter:

```
# THE_REQUEST will include the query string so you can get it here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /show_table\.php\?table=([0-9]{1,2})
RewriteRule ^show_table\.php$ http://example.com/table/%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: You need to escape the `\?` in THE_REQUEST RewriteCond regex

Comment: @AnetteD. Glad to help. Are you going with the two `RewriteCond` version or the combined one?

Comment: Could I ask just about the "full redirection"? Is also possible to "small redirection"? Because I want to use same .htaccess on my localhost and on website, but if I place "/table/%1?" or "./table/%1?" to redir rule, I receive "http://localhost/C:/wamp/www/example_com/table/12" instead of "http://localhost/example_com/table/12"

Comment: @AnetteD. I will have to think about that for a while to come up with a solution. Myself - I would create a VirtualHost in Apache so that the development environment is also at the document root `localhost/table/12` instead of in a subdirectory `localhost/example_com/table/12` so that development closely resembles production. Trying to accommodate different redirection paths with mod_rewrite in that way is a little hacky.